# Firebase phone auth not working on android 11 after migrating the project to different pc

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I just changed my pc on which I code few days ago.

I copied my previous flutter project to it and managed to run it in the new system after some workarounds.

Previous pc and new pc both are windows 10.

Now When I run it on android 7 the firebase phone auth works perfectly but when i try to run it on android 11 it doesn’t sends Otp.

I have submitted both sha 256 and sha 32 in firebase console.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new SHA fingerprint to your Firebase console , I think it's causing for SafetyNet